# How to hide Console.ReadKey() user input?

Tags: c#, console-application, user-input

I'm making a Fahrenheit to Celsius converter (a very simple one, because I'm very new) and when I use `Console.ReadKey()` it displays the character the user pressed to the screen. Is there a way to hide the user input?

```
cki = Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `Console.ReadKey(true)`

Answer (score 18):

There is an overload [`ReadKey(bool)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which determines whether or not to hide the character. So you want:

```
cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for not being rude, because I know this is a noob question! :)                                                                                                        Edit-I think the bool should be set to true to prevent seeing the character pressed.

Comment: @CoderShmoder you really should check the API before asking. That is how I found out about this overload.